# Exclude basemap from Map Series extent clipping

Tags: arcgis-pro, extents, map-series

I am working on making a spatial map series in ArcGIS Pro. I turned the "Clip to Index Feature" box on, as I only want the specific property we want mapped to show up on the map, not the neighboring parcels.

Is there a way to exclude the basemap from this clipping, so that the basemap is still shown outside of the parcel boundaries?

Essentially I want it exactly how it is in the attached image, but with the basemap imagery extending beyond the red parcel boundary lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In that option, there is a dropdown list and you can exclude any layer:

In the attached screenshot I have clipped all layers except the two that I have selected (one is the basemap).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Esri documentation:

> Optionally, choose map layers to exclude from clipping by checking
> them in the Exclude layers from clipping menu. Layers excluded from
> clipping extend beyond the clipping edges.

See details at:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/clip-layers-in-a-map.htm#GUID-A6499777-C4BD-43EA-A2D3-3D4729363A53

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out how to do what I wanted using the page query function, setting it to only show the parcel boundaries when the owner name matched the index field name.